# Finder/Quicklook Bug (File Icon Previews Not Working)

Tags: finder, icon, quicklook

My Macbook has suddenly stopped generating preview icon of all file types. So all files are now replaced by their respective generic file type icons (see picture attached). Moreover, when I quicklook any file, the preview appears corrupted.

I have not updated any software recently, nor have I modified any file systems.

Any help would be much appreciated!

[image: Corrupted Quicklook and Icons]

Comment: First thing I'd try would be to run "sudo qlmanage -r" in a terminal, which will reset the QuickLook subsystem.

Comment: Cool... I'll add it as a proper answer then, didn't think it'd be that easy :)

Comment: This worked for me: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/436449/415526

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comment under original question, first thing I'd try (which turned out to be the solution) would be to run `sudo qlmanage -r` in a terminal, which resets the QuickLook subsystem.

Answer (score 0):

Merely running sudo qlmanage -r did not fix this issue for me.

For me, the direct cause was QLStephen.qlgenerator. The issue happened overnight and I suspect Apple's latest silent OS X update may have played a part in this. I removed the plugin the same way I installed it (Homebrew); if you manually installed it, simply drag it out of the plugins folder in your Library and run sudo qlmanage -r

Thong.qlgenerator also caused an issue for me (PNG only showed as an icon).

Answer (score 0):

From MacRumors:

- Open Activity Monitor
- Search for a process called `com.apple.quicklook.ThumbnailsAgent``
- Force quit the process
- Force quite Finder (from the Force Quit menu)

[image]